# How to read arduino flash memory

Tags: arduino

Imagine i'have lost my source code.
Is there a way to dump an arduino flash memory ?
What i want to do is to get an hex file on my PC that represent byte per byte the arduino flash memory (including bootloader)

I have 3 arduino types:

- Arduino UNO (rev3)
- Arduino MEGA
- Leonardo Ethernet

Thanks

Comment: This might depend on your particular model.

Comment: thanks. See my edits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`avrdude` can do that for you.  The specifics will depend on which arduino you have, but something like:

```
avrdude -p m328p -P usb -c usbtiny -U flash:r:flash.bin:r
```

will get you the contents of the flash memory.

Here's a site with more info:

http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/avr-basics-reading-and-writing-flash-contents/

Comment: Thanks: Do you know which programmer i should pass as -c argument for this device: https://store.arduino.cc/product/A000092

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using an Arduino board, the programmer (option `-c`) must be set to `arduino` (see the [`avrdude` manual](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html) for details). Also, I had to specify the ACM port (in my case `/dev/ttyACM0` on a Linux machine).

The full command to read (and backup the flash to `flash.bin`) is thus:

```sh
avrdude -p m328p -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c arduino -U flash:r:flash.bin:r
```

And to restore the flash, you can use:

```sh
avrdude -p m328p -P /dev/ttyACM0 -c arduino -U flash:w:flash.bin
```

Comment: can i read only the bootloader?!